# Matrix total_rows variable not updating after adding rows manually

Tags: matrix, pixelandtonic

I have a custom add-on which adds a row to the exp_matrix_data DB table. Everything works well with the exception that the `{field_name:total_rows}` tag is no longer returning the correct number of matrix rows.

Are there any places other than exp_matrix_data where my add-on needs to make changes when programatically adding/deleting matrix rows in this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oops, not to worry I think I figured it out - I needed to set `field_id_##` in `exp_channel_data` to `1`.